# Spring boot websocket ping/pong

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-websocket

Websocket implementation with spring boot to test ping /pong protocol

```
public class HandlePingRequest implements WebSocketHandler {

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }



    @Override
    public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession session, WebSocketMessage<?> message) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       log.info("received websocket  message {}",message);
       Thread.sleep(30000);
       session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Response message"));
        
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(WebSocketSession session, Throwable exception) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus closeStatus) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsPartialMessages() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

Client implement in python

```
import websocket
import time
websocket.enableTrace(True)
ws = websocket.WebSocket()


ws.connect("ws://localhost:8080/v0")
ws.ping()
ws.send('Hello')
ws.ping()
time.sleep(800)
ws.close()
```

when the server is handling a text message or binary message, the server does not respond to the ping until it send an response for the text/binary or in the RFC it says the server should respond immediately.
In this exemple the response for the second ping is received 30s after the request.

Was expecting that the ping/pong message be handled by tomcat/jetty server, so how it is possible to handle the received ping message on the websocket handler instead of let the server handle it?

Comment: The code sleeps for 30 seconds, so not sure why it would be expected to "respond immediately".

Comment: As mentionned on RFC6455 "A Ping frame MAY include "Application data".
 Upon receipt of a Ping frame, an endpoint MUST send a Pong frame in
   response, unless it already received a Close frame.  It SHOULD
   respond with Pong frame as soon as is practical".The first ping response is received immediatly